# How can i show 'thank you page' on form submission in HTML UI Service ? It does not support doPost() so how will i get the values on next page

Tags: google-apps-script

I tried creating a preview page of form submitted on an HTML UI service page. But there's no way to get the values on next page. How can I show 'thank you page' on form submission in HTML-UI Service ? It does not support doPost() so how will I get the values on next page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `doPost` in the .gs code and create a special page for the 'thank you'.

test [online here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxhxfjOsInchepTRfHFVPA6SGZyleDLWIRsjrVA3DjLawt3hZtu/exec)

in .gs file :

```
function doPost(e){
sendForm(e);  
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('postMessage.html');
  template.email = e.parameter.email;
  return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}
```

postMessage.html  ( email is a variable name I get in the form...)

```
<div>
Thanks,
You entered <?= email ?>
</div>
```